# Delphi: overload + jmp/call

Tags: delphi, ассемблер

Есть несколько overload-функций. Нужно выполнить прыжок на ассемблере инструкцией jmp (ну или call) в одну из них. Как указать именно нужную из overload-функций, если они все называются одинаково?

Comment: На самом деле, под капотом эти функции называются не одинаково. Посмотрите, какой код генерирует Delphi в таких случаях и какие имена использует.

Comment: @zed, прикол в том, что имена абсолютно одинаковые. И в map-файле, и в dcu, и в exe (когда добавляется отладочная инфа). И даже при генерации obj.

Comment: Да, действительно. Оказалось не всё так просто. Но есть обходной путь - см. ответ.

Comment: @zed, имена не одинаковые только в пакетах (.bpl), если я правильно помню, потому что там к имени типы параметров добавляются.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать определить типизированные указатели с разными именами на нужные функции и использовать их.

Пример:

```
const
  MyIntToStr32: function (Value: Integer): string = SysUtils.IntToStr;
  MyIntToStr64: function (Value: Int64): string = SysUtils.IntToStr;

asm
  ...
  call [MyIntToStr64]
end;
```

Comment: Вариант, конечно. Но это всё равно костыль, а хочется как-то без них обойтись :(

Comment: Есть, конечно, ещё и такой вариант: назвать функции по-разному и сделать несколько inline-функций с одинаковыми (нужными) названиями. Но такой вариант не будет работать в D7, а хочется, чтобы и там работал...

Comment: А ещё проблема в этом (моём с инлайнами) методе в том, что эти функции с различающимися именами нельзя скрыть в inplementation-секции, нужно обязательно их в interface размещать...

Comment: А подсмотреть в скомпилированном коде как их сама Delphi вызывает - не получится?

Comment: @Alekcvp, так Delphi же **в коде** вызывает их не по именам, а по жёстко прописанным ссылкам (абсолютным или относительным), которые не узнаешь, пока не скомпилишь программу (и каждый раз они будут разными)

Comment: @JinX, насколько я помню, в дебаггере cpu-view показываются не смещения/адреса, а именно имена функций. Вот интересно что там отображается для перегруженных функций. Просто дельфи сейчас под рукой нет.

Comment: @Alekcvp там отображается имя функции, как оно есть в коде. И нет никаких признаков того, какая именно версия из набора перегруженных вызовется.